# Should I make one abstract class with many derived classes or just one general class?

Tags: oop, drawing

C++ Should I make one abstract class with many derived classes or just one general class?

Classic example is the abstract Shape object with derived classes Square and Triangle that hold specific geometry and functions.

Why don't I just make one general class called Shape that includes a more general geometry data member to hold a dynamic amount of points that could either be a square or a triangle?
Functions could take some parameter indicating what type of shape it was e.g. Shape.process("square");  instead of something like Square.process();

Is my question clear? Is this purely a stylistic choice?

Comment: What is your real problem ? You should try to solve a specific situation, not applying general rules everywhere.

Comment: Thats not a question specific to C++, is a general OOP dessign question. And, on the other hand, real C++ dessigns doesn't do things in that manner. C++ is not OOP only, is multiparadigm, and generic in the most cases. In this case (Drawing system) I would never do a dynamic-binding based/OO hierarchy: Has performance issues (cache and vtables are not good friends), and a lot of coupling (The drawing system is too coupled with the entity system).

Comment: Polymorphic class hierarchies should only be used if you truly cannot know the actual types you need until runtime. If you know everything at compile time already, you don't need dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: This type of question is EXPLICITLY forbidden in the help section.  SO is not for questions of opinion.

Comment: @xaxxon It is a subjective question to be sure, but it wasn't my intent to gather opinions so much as guidelines to use for solving a design problem.

Comment: The Square/Triangle example is a very simple one to help understand what inheritance is. when to actually use it all depends on the type of project you have. It's not stylistic but more what is practical for the current problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating "god" classes that do a bunch of stuff. What if you will have to implement a lot of shapes? A class should have only one responsibility,  should be open for extension and closed for modifications.  Check the class design principles or the SOLID principles of design. You should avoid complicated design and big classes that have multiple responsibilities just because at a moment it will become a pain to maintain them or add extra functionality. Unit testing will also be something more easy to do with a good design.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of SOLID; I will check it out thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this reasoning lead me to conclude that I need a class for small rectangles, medium rectangles, sqrt(2) sized rectangles, large rectanges and so on? I'm having trouble seeing where the distinction is made.

Comment: No, it should not lead you to that conclusion.  The whole idea is to follow the KISS OFF method (Keep it Simple, Stupid, or Face Frustration).  Having separate classes for different sized rectangles (which all have the same data members and methods) is NOT keeping it simple.

Comment: The idea is to have something simple to maintain,  readable. Following the principles leads to simplicity in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get an answer to this type of question in general.  It is going to depend on the situation and requirements for whatever problem you are attempting to solve.  In some cases, it will make sense to have an interface with derived classes.  In others, it will make sense to have a generalized class.  Without knowing the requirements for the problem, you will get no real answer.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on what you need the `Shape` for.   For example if you are just drawing it, then yeah a general `Shape` class that just draws line from point to point would be perfect (for polygons anyway).  But what if you wanted to calculate the area.  It would probably be easier to have a `Square` and `Triangle` class where the `getArea()` function uses the appropriate area formula.  There is no hard and fast rule it simply depends on what you need them for